# Как сделать воспроизведение видео на сайте через торрент? Торрент-видео-плеер?

Tags: javascript, java

Может кто знает, умеет. Господа. Пожалуйста подскажите, как построить собственный плеер или перестроить существующий плеер так, чтобы воспроизведение видео-файла шло не с url адреса, а через торрент. А?

Comment: Видеохостинг PeerTube специализируется на показе через торренты, например

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходим  Java Media Framework (JMF) API.

Comment: Можете рабочий пример показать?